# What happens to an insert when a mysql(innoDB) table is being altered(locked)?

Tags: mysql, database, server, innodb

I am trying to `ALTER` a database column by using:

```
ALTER TABLE [table name] MODIFY id bigint;
```

I searched and found out that the table gets locked during the `ALTER` process.

How do the inserts get affected during the `ALTER` process? Do they wait until the lock is released? Is there a timeout?

If the inserts wait for the lock to be released, is there a limit of how many inserts that could wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change a data type using `CHANGE` or `MODIFY`, MySQL tries to convert existing column values to the new type as well as possible.

When the `ALTER TABLE` finish the convertion all pending DML will execute.

The time that it'll take depends on the amount of data the table have.

Comment: subject to timeouts.